# Iterating Regex Named Groups

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to iterate each named group in a regular expression (i.e. - `(?<name>.*)`) and depending on the name of the group set an instance property or add it to a collection.  Important part is I will never know the name of the group when using the regular expression so I cannot use the string indexer on my Match.  Is there a way to extract the names for my groups within my Match?

Comment: probably inefficient, but you could write a regex to parse your regex and extract the named capture groups in the form of "(?<name>.*)" and could then iterate using that list...

Comment: @marduk: Benny did use the named-group syntax, but it didn't show up because he didn't use backticks to code-format the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Regex.GroupNameFromNumber` to iterate over all the capturing groups in the regex and find their names.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnamefromnumber.aspx